# Removing an apostrophe from a Django Jinja Template?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I would like to remove an apostrophe from a Django template variable in HTML using Jinja.

The variable `item.product` is `Paul's Phone` which I am using to open a Boostrap Modal:

```
id="move_{{ item.product|cut:' ' }}"
```

This will remove the spaces, which is good. The outcome now is `Paul'sPhone`, but I can't remove the apostrophe by doing this:

```
data-target="#move_{{ item.product|cut:' ', ''' }}"
```

How do I get around these tags to remove the apostrophe from that variable?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the apostrophe is surrounded by apostrophes too? I can’t check whether it works, but have you tried this? data-target='#move_{{ item.product|cut:" ", "'" }}'

Comment: that's not Jinja, that's a django template. Jinja would be something like `product|cut(" ")`

Comment: It is Django, yes, but isn't the templating language still Jinja? 

Despite that - solved the issue. I Will put the answer. Was a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The best way around this is to not forget Django has already set up everything with an "ID".

Just use `data-target="#move_{{ item.id }}"`

- this was my gift of rookie error to you!